# Solving $\pmb{S}=\pmb{R_o}-\frac{\pmb{t_on}^T}{d}$ for $\pmb{t_o}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices $\pmb{S}, \pmb{R_o}\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$, one vector $\pmb{n}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\pmb{n}$ is normalized and one scalar $d\in\mathbb{R}^+$. $\pmb S = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac1s
\end{matrix}\right)$, with $s>1$ and $\pmb {R_o}$ a 3d rotation matrix.

If I want to solve

$$\pmb{S}=\pmb{R_o}-\frac{\pmb{t_on}^T}{d}$$

for $\pmb{t_o}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ I do the following (obvious) steps:

$$\pmb{t_on}^T = d(\pmb{R_o}-\pmb{S})$$

Now I do multiply with $\pmb n$ from the right side. Since $\pmb{n}^T\pmb{n}=\Vert\pmb{n}\Vert_2^2 = 1$ it follows:
$$\pmb{t_o} = d(\pmb{R_o}-\pmb{S})\pmb n.$$

The problem is, if I put my solution back in the initial equation I end up with this:

$$\pmb{R_o} - \pmb{S} = (\pmb{R_o} - \pmb{S})\pmb{n}\pmb{n}^T,$$

which would be correct if $\pmb{n}\pmb{n}^T=\pmb{Id}$, but this cannot be the case (because this matrix has only rank one). Anyway, I again can mutliply with $\pmb n$ from the right to get equality.

Nevertheless, if I plug that computation in my system (Matlab) and want to verify that I got the correct $\pmb{t_o}$ by checking the initial equation for equality with $\pmb S$ I get inequality. Of course I get equality if I check for $\pmb{Sn}=\pmb{R_on}-\frac{\pmb{t_on}^T}{d}\pmb n$

Is there a way to solve for $\pmb t_o$, s.t. the initial equation holds without multiplying with $\pmb n$? Does there actually exist a solution, because I have an overdetermined system - three variables, but nine equations (if I compare the matrices elementwise, before mutliplying with $\pmb n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Almost* everything you've done is correct. Your conclusion -- that for the first equation to hold, you must have
$$
t_0 = d(R_0 - S) n,
$$
is correct, and hence that for the first equation to hold, you must have
$$
R_0 - S = (R_0 - S) nn^t.
$$
That means that *either* $R_0 - S$ is zero or that $nn^t$ is the identity.  Since it's not (ever!), you know that either $R_0 = S$ *or* there's no solution to the equation. In the case that $R_0 = S$, you can also see that $n = 0$ is the only solution.

Comment: The problem is then there is never a solution I guess, because $R_o$ is a rotation matrix and $S$ can not be a rotation matrix. Do I get it right then, that I can solve for $t_o$, but the solution does not fit to the initial equation?

Comment: Yes; if you have the restriction $s > 1$, then there appears to be no solution. To say "I can solve for $t_0$" is a little odd, What you mean is "If $t_0$ is a solution, it must satisfy this simpler formula." But you cannot claim that the thing you found is a solution, which is what we usually mean by "I can solve ..."

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!